# How do I persist VLAN settings on my Asus RT-AC68 Router?

Tags: router, vlan, asuswrt-merlin

I have achieved the desired vlan settings on my Asus router by using robocfg.  However, when I reboot the router those settings are lost. I'm running the latest firmware as of this writing (3.0.0.4.384_45149).

```
robocfg vlan 22 ports "1t 3u"
robocfg vlan 1 ports "1 2 4 5t"
```

Searching around on forums, people are suggesting that settings can be persisted by writing scripts and storing them in the folder `/jffs/scripts/`. It also says that this feature needs to be enabled in the UI under `Administration -> System`.  However, in my version of the firmware I do not see any settings regarding scripts or jffs settings.

Here is the script I have created at `/jffs/scripts/services-start`

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/000vlanconfiged
robocfg vlan 22 ports "1t 3u"
robocfg vlan 1 ports "1 2 4 5t"
```

I also tried `/jffs/scripts/post-mount` and that didn't work either.  The vlan settings are unchanged and the file was not created in the tmp folder.

Answer (score 1):

The commands look good for me.
Did you set the proper file permissions?

I'd guess you are missing the "execute" permission. 
Try to chmod 755 your services-start file.